Ubuntu 22.04 file manager has an extra "2" in the upper right corner of the icon on the dock bar
I used ubuntu 22.04 and connected the file manager to smb, and copied files from it to a USB flash drive. There were no problems in the middle. Later, I changed to another USB flash drive to copy, and it seemed that there was a problem with the USB flash drive, so nothing was written in. I discovered these operations yesterday at noon. I turned on the computer last night and opened clash verge rev, which showed a download speed of 60Mb/s per second. I turned it off, and suddenly I found an extra prompt "2" on the file manager. I have restarted countless times, but the problem is still there, and according to cluade, it has not been solved. Does anyone have any ideas?


Isn't that a notification? Click on the date (in top bar) to display notifications.

You have notifications from your file manager (Files application). You can see them by clicking on the clock/date in the middle of the upper part of your display. If you click there the numbers will vanish. There you see many other notifications from your system.
Showing the clock/date part:

